# parameters in c#

Tags: c#, parameters, casting

I have some parameters that are being passed but having some casting issues and am wondering whats the best way to do this.

```
ReportExecution2005.ParameterValue[] parameters
parameters[0].Label = "reportID";
parameters[0].Value = "5";   /* I want to pass a variable here not an actual string value -- I want it to be of type int. I tried to cast with no luck*/
parameters[1].Label = "ReportName";
parameters[1].Value = reportName;
parameters[2].Value = reportID.ToString;
```

Comment: How are you casting the variable? A simple `.ToString();` should work.

Comment: @tobias86 `ToString()` works okay here with an `int` but `ToString()` can easily be overloaded and may not return a straight cast. Best not to assume it will return what you expect.

Answer (score 6):

Take your int variable, and do `.ToString()` at the end. That will turn it into a string. You can't cast an `int` to a `string` because - as commented - there is no implicit conversion between them.

Comment: Not only do you not need to cast, as the OP found out, you can't.  There is no explicit conversion from `int` to `string`.

Comment: Thanks for the response J Steen but that doesnt work either as you can see in my initial post. parameter[2].value = reportID.ToString is an int. The error i get is "cannot convert method group ToString" to non delegate type string

Comment: @user1281748 `ToString` is a method; you need to add parenthesis at the end: `ToString();`

Comment: @Servy The "no need to cast" was a turn of speech. I know there's no explicit conversion from int to string. =)

Comment: facepalm on that, thanks servy. however im concerned that if my report in SSRS is using a stored procedure expecting int and im using a parameter that is a string. It wont work. Whats your thoughts?